# How to remove dynamically added label in C# WFA?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a problem when trying to remove a label from controls.
I have 6 tabpages in a tabcontrol that should have the same output.
I used a checkbox to add the elements, which works fine.
Whenever i try to remove a label from the controls, the label is still visible.
I am unsure if im refering to the label incorrectly or if there is some other way to do this.
Also tried using Dispose() with no success. Please excuse the bad english.

```
 private void tabpages_Feltolt()
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.Controls)
        {
            if (tabControl1.Controls.IndexOf(tab)!=tabControl1.Controls.IndexOf(tabPage_Meret))
            {
                CheckBox checkBox_sikmaras = new CheckBox()
                {
                    Parent = this,
                    Location = new Point(10, 10),
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Tag=index,
                };
                Label label_checkbox_sikmaras = new Label()
                {
                    Parent = this,
                    Location = new Point(25, 10),
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Text = "Síkmarás",
                };
                checkBox_sikmaras.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_sikmaras_CheckedChanged;
                Control[] controls = new Control[]
                {
                checkBox_sikmaras,
                label_checkbox_sikmaras,
                };
                tab.Controls.AddRange(controls);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    private void CheckBox_sikmaras_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox sikmaras = (CheckBox)sender;
        TabPage tab = tabControl1.TabPages[(int)sikmaras.Tag];
        Label label_sikmaras_tabla = new Label()
        {
            Parent = this,
            Location = new Point(10, 25),
            AutoSize = true,
            Text = "Síkmarás",
            Name = Convert.ToString(sikmaras.Tag),
        };
        Control[] controls = new Control[]
        {
            label_sikmaras_tabla,
        };
        if (sikmaras.Checked)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages[(int)sikmaras.Tag].Controls.AddRange(controls);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                if (tab.Controls.Contains(control))
                {
                    Control controltoremove = tabControl1.TabPages[Convert.ToInt32(sikmaras.Tag)].Controls[Convert.ToString(sikmaras.Tag)];
                    tabControl1.TabPages[(int)sikmaras.Tag].Controls.Remove(controltoremove);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First.
You are creating a new instance of Label in CheckBox_sikmaras_CheckedChanged every time it's called. That's why `if (tab.Controls.Contains(control))` always returns false. Although their fields are identical it's not the same label.

Second.
Why get controltoremove from TabPage, if you already know that it contains it from `if (tab.Controls.Contains(control))`? Just remove it.

Here is example of working code.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label_sikmaras_tabla = new Label()
        {
            Location = new Point(10, 25),
            AutoSize = true,
            Text = "Síkmarás",
            //Name = Convert.ToString(sikmaras.Tag),
        };
    }

    Label label_sikmaras_tabla;

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox sikmaras = (CheckBox)sender;
        sikmaras.Tag = 1;
        TabPage tab = tabControl1.TabPages[(int)sikmaras.Tag];
        Control[] controls = new Control[]
        {
            label_sikmaras_tabla,
        };
        if (sikmaras.Checked)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages[(int)sikmaras.Tag].Controls.AddRange(controls);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                if (tab.Controls.Contains(control))
                {
                    //Control controltoremove = tabControl1.TabPages[Convert.ToInt32(sikmaras.Tag)]
                    //    .Controls[Convert.ToString(sikmaras.Tag)];

                    tabControl1.TabPages[(int)sikmaras.Tag].Controls.Remove(control);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```